# cma-reserved region appears to be 0 KB even if I added a 'linux,cma node' in the device tree

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-device-driver

I wanted to test cma-allocator in linux (5.15.68).
So I added linux,cma node in the /reserved-memory node like this.

```
reserved-memory {
    #address-cells = <2>;
    #size-cells = <2>;
    ranges;

    axpu_reserved_mem: axpursvd@90000000 {
        no-map;
        reg = <0x0 0xc0000000 0x0 0x8000000>;
    };

    linux,cma {
        compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
        reusable;
        size = <0 0x30000000>;
        alloc-ranges = <0 0x90000000 0 0x30000000>;
        linux,cma-default;
    };
};
```

BTW, this test was done on qemu arm64 machine and there is only 1GB ram (from 0x80000000 ~ 0xbfffffff) in the virtual machine, and notice I'm assigning 3/4 of the ram to cma region and 1/8 to a device driver (just for test).

When I boot the machine, I see this message during the boot.

```
Memory: 1020140K/1048576K available (3200K kernel code, 386K rwdata, 808K rodata, 7808K init, 106K bss, 28436K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
```

Why is the CMA-reserved area is 0KB?
This is some config variables I added for CMA test.

```
CONFIG_MEMORY_ISOLATION=y
CONFIG_CONTIG_ALLOC=y
ONFIG_CMA=y
CONFIG_CMA_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_CMA_DEBUGFS=y
CONFIG_CMA_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_CMA_AREAS=7
# CONFIG_DMA_CMA is not set
```

I tried adding 'cma=768MB' in the boot args or changed CONFIG_CMA_AREAS to 1 but it is the same.
What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found by adding CONFIG_CMA_DMA=y, the cma-alloc area is reserved.
When I add 'cma=768M' in the boot args, it has the precedence, (I don't know where the kernel placed the cma region).
But when there is no 'cma=768M' in the boot args, the device tree information is used and the CMA area is placed from 0x90000000 as I wanted.